# I need to pull non matching numbers from 2 columns excel into new sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 2 large columns (139456 records) per column. I need to extract the non matching records to a new sheet "call sheet". 
I will be adding to bottom of both list as time goes on. I would like to have it ad the non matching records to the bottom of the "call sheet". I have come close to getting done but excel seems to be overloaded. I keep getting the not responding error.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$1999,MATCH(0,IFERROR(MATCH($A$2:$A$1999,$B$2:$B$399,0),COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,$A$2:$A$1999)),0)),"")
```

> ***Overloads due to number of records***

Comment: Welcome to Super User, yes it's very much possible that due to huge Database and may be slower Processor, Excel is unable to extract rows. I would like to suggest either use VBA (Macro) or if possible break Database into pieces.

Comment: VBA would be great. Thanks. I will be looking for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I jury rigged some old code of mine to take all data out of "Column 1" that **doesn't** match any data in "Column 2" and print it in Another sheet.
Maybe it can be of some use to use, you might have to tweak it a bit.

It starts with the variables on where your lists are and where you want the new list to go – might want to do these variable, to grow with the columns.

```
Sub sort()
Dim list1 As Range, list2 As Range, c As Range, outSht As Worksheet, outCol As String, Lrow As Long
'---Options---
Set list1 = Range("A2:A1999")   'Range of first column
Set list2 = Range("B2:B399")    'Range of second column
Set outSht = Sheets("Sheet2")   'Output Sheet (Create one first)
outCol = "A"                    'Output Column

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
oCN = Columns(outCol).Column
For Each c In list1
    If list2.Find(c.Value) Is Nothing Then
        lRow = outSht.Range(outCol & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        outSht.Cells(lRow + 1, oCN).Value = c.Value
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It's not very fast, but at least it doesn't end up with an error.
I tried with 45000 entries in Column 1 and 400 in Column 2, and that took me about *6 seconds* to generate the list.

**Warning**
Tried with 220k rows checking against 100k rows. And after 15 minutes, it's still running. So yeah, if you want to use this, I hope you only have to run it once.

You could make it automatic, but then you probably want a faster method, or one that only looks at the last added value.
Also note that this will just add everything twice if run twice. It doesn't clear the list first.

**EDIT 2**

A much faster way of doing it, would be a macro which makes it a table, sorts out the relevant data, copies the data and then removes the table.
It managed all the 220 000 entries in manners of seconds. I just have to figure out how to copy the things NOT matching the list, rather than the other way around.

**Edit 3**

Have yet to figure out the autofilter stuff.
But if you haven't used that other code, and still want to, use this instead:

```
Sub ArrayIt()
Dim aArray As Variant, bArray As Variant
aArray = [transpose(A2:A139456)]
bArray = [transpose(B2:B139456)]
Set outSht = Sheets("Sheet2")   'Output Sheet (Create one first)
outCol = "A"                    'Output Column
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
oCN = Columns(outCol).Column
For Each c In aArray

    If IsError(Application.Match(c, bArray, 0)) Then
        Lrow = outSht.Range(outCol & outSht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        outSht.Cells(Lrow + 1, oCN).Value = c   
    End If
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It's basically the same thing, but converts the data to arrays first, and then use them to go through it.
It's still slow, but it's at least 20 times faster, if not more.
Managed 220k x 220k entries in less than 2 minutes.

**Edit 4**

Ok, so I did a workaround on the Autofilter.
**Issues:**
Can only *show* the values in my filter, not *hide them.
Can only work with the values that are shown.
Can't delete rows with or without data (too slow).

**Solution:**
So here is what the new code does:
First, it copes the range we want to work with – Column "A" – to two new columns, just to make sure it won't mess up the original list.
Then it makes the first copy into a table, and filter it with our second range – Column "B".
Then, it clears the content of every visible cell in the table and removes the table.
Now the first copy is only the data we want, and a bunch of holes, where it cleared all unwanted data. So now we make that range our new filter.
Now the second copy becomes a table, and is sorted with the new filter.
Then the visible cells – now the data we want – gets copied to another column.

Currently, the code does it all on the same sheet. And it takes up column `M` to `Q`. So beware that when testing it out, as it will mess thing up if there is other data there, and probably also if there is some kind of sorting and hidden rows in the sheet.

There's bound to be a better way to write the actual code, but this is as good as I have time with. It managed to run the current setting (225 000 rows of data 100 000 parameters for filter) in **12 seconds**.

```
Sub aaTablefiltering()
Dim LO As ListObject, tName As String, rOne As Range, rTwo As Range, rThree As Range, rFour As Range, fArr As Variant

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Set rOne = Range("A2:A225000")
Set rTwo = Range("B2:B100000")
Set rThree = Range("M2:M225001")
Set fFour = Range("O2:O225001")
fArr = [transpose(B2:B100000)]
tName = "DTable"

rOne.Copy Destination:=Range("M2")
rOne.Copy Destination:=Range("O2")

Set LO = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rThree, , xlNo)
LO.Name = tName
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=fArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DTable").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DTable").Unlist
fArr = [transpose(M2:M225001)]

Set LO = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, fFour, , xlNo)
LO.Name = tName
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DTable").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=fArr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DTable").Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("Q1")
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("DTable").Unlist
Range("M:Q").ClearFormats
Range("M:O").ClearContents

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I think your on the right track. I will run it. Thanks for the share.

Comment: This works faster but only seems to return a partial list. The first code returned 31283 non matching . This code returns 8201. I cant see a reason for the limited output/difference.

Comment: That's interesting. Haven't had time to test it properly, so maybe there's something wrong with it.

Comment: I add data to columnB daily and need to pull only updated data for export to another program. The first macro is slower but works fine. I would like to delete data on sheet2 before running macro. I'm looking for only updated data each time I run. Right now it adds to the bottom of sheet2. I have to delete old data then run macro. Would be great if I could ad to the code so it deletes old before running. I have a macro for deleting data in a column but I can't get to ad in this one.

Comment: Sub SmartClientDeleteColumns()

Columns("A").Delete

End Sub

Comment: Yeah, this only adds to the end. I guess you could add `outSht.Columns("A").Delete` before the loop or something, if that's valid.